# Как избавиться от <div>?

Tags: javascript

Как мне добавить .prog_container в #Collage0 без обёртки в div?

```
<div id="Collage0">
<div class="prog_container"></div>
<div class="prog_container"></div>
<div class="prog_container"></div>
</div>
<script>
$('#Collage0').append($('<div>').load(link + ' .prog_container', function(){
      addDrag('ex-drag');
  }));
</script>
```

Чтобы получилось вроде этого:

```
$('#Collage0').append(load(link + ' .prog_container', function(){
      addDrag('ex-drag');
  }));
```

Comment: А в обёртку чего тогда??

Comment: В id="Collage0"